# Capturing cURL trace using Fiddler2 (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, docusignapi

As recommended by my DocuSign account manager, I am using Fiddler2 to capture the necessary trace for API certification.  I am unable to retrieve the trace from the DocuSign domain and have narrowed it down to the fact that these are cURL calls.

According to Fiddler2, http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigurePHPcURL, the advice is to add the following to code:
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
where $ch = curl_init().

I've also tried
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');

Still no dice.  I only get traffic from my application site.  The following is all of my curl code:

```
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd()     ."/**the cert info");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');//allows fiddler to see requests
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

It's definitely talking to the DocuSign domain as my application is working, I'm just trying to get the trace.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

fiddler is client side program, it cannot see server traffic to other servers only traffic between client and server.

Unless your server is running locally (on the same computer that you are running fiddler) using 127.0.0.1 this will not work as 127.0.0.1 is the loopback ip for the computer, in this case the server would be trying to use itself as a proxy (which would be ok if the server computer itself was the one running fiddler). You need to change the ip to the computer running fiddler and make sure the server can access that port.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same scenario, and I used a protocol analyzer such as Wireshark or TCPDUMP to see HTTP traffic at network level.

Of course the server needs to be running locally. Bellow you can find a screenshot example of traffic capture where you can clearly see the HTTP GET going out.

[image]